# Elegant way to wrap components with a helper method in React Native / React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Following [this article](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-react-context-a7592dfdcbc) about context, we are using a helper method **withContext** (definition below) to trickle down theme related information.

This works for components (the context is passed as props):

```
export const Empty = (props) => <View>
    <Text>{props.children}</Text>
</View>;

export default withContext(Empty);
```

However, we prefer calling the withContext where the component is used and not at the definition:

```
import {withContext} from "./utils/context";

import Empty from "./layout_modules/empty/Empty";

Empty = withContext(Empty);
```

The problem is *import statements* are probably transpiled to const which leads to this error:

> "Empty" is read-only error.

Using require works but is complex:

```
const Empty = withContext(require("./layout_modules/empty/Empty").Empty);
```

Any elegant way to use import and invoke withContext?

**Method's definition:**

```
const allTypes = {
    locale: PropTypes.string,
    colors: PropTypes.object,
    i18n: PropTypes.object,
    fontFamily: PropTypes.object,
};

const consumeContext = (contextTypes) => (Component) => {
    const ContextConsumer = (props, context) =>
        <Component {...props} {...context} />;
    ContextConsumer.contextTypes = contextTypes;
    return ContextConsumer;
};

export const withContext = (Component) => {
    return consumeContext(allTypes)(Component);
}
```

Comment: So, where in your module do you actually *use* `Empty`?

Comment: No, `import` statements are not exactly transpiled to `const`, but yes you cannot assign to imported bindings. Just use a different name.